# In Objective C, Usual implementation of singleton design pattern contains "static id theInstance = nil" in a method, why not outside?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, singleton, static-methods

When i was going through Singleton design pattern in Objective C, I found lot of people using the below code to create it.

```
@interface Base : NSObject {} 

+(id)instance;
@end

@implementation Base

+(id) instance
{

static id theInstance = nil;

    if (theInstance == nil)
    {
        theInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return theInstance;
}

@end
```

Here i did not get the why do we have to assign the static variable to nil in a method instead it can be declared outside the method and assigned to nil. 
Because everytime this +instance() method is called, theInstance variable will be assigned to nil.
Will it not lose its previous object to which it was pointing to?

I have tried debugging it, surprisingly , it will not point to nil when +instance() method is called.
Can anyone explain me whats happening here?

Comment: Its wrong and it should be outside the getter so that its initialized only once.

Comment: @PraveenS, that's clearly not true.  Did you try it?

Comment: @CarlNorum : Thanks for the clarification, i was unaware of the initialization of static variables regardless of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` variables only get initialized once, regardless of if they're at global or local scope.  In this case, you don't even need the `nil` - `static` storage class variables are zero-initialized by default.  This declaration:

```
  static id theInstance;
```

is enough to be the same as what you have there.

Comment: Nice answer this, the scope based init for static variables was something new i learnt today.

Comment: Add a suggestion to switch to `dispatch_once` and +1.

Comment: I don't know anything about `dispatch_once`.  I'm no Objective-C programmer, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Carl. I did not know the fact that static variables will be initialized only once no matter where they are initialized.

Comment: The answer explains why it works. The reason why you _should_ put the static variable inside the method is that it makes it impossible to modify the variable except by calling the method, so the reader of the method _knows_ that nobody will ever set theInstance to any different value.